# Cannot import any default exports (typescript & rollup), but only named exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import, rollup

I started a new Lit2 project building custom web components, but I'm having issues importing external libraries. I used the project generator as suggested in the Lit2 Docs, https://open-wc.org/docs/development/generator/.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": ["es2016", "esnext", "dom"],
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "outDir": "build",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "rootDir": "./",
        "incremental": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "noLib": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Here is my rollup.config.js

```
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import html from '@web/rollup-plugin-html';
import { importMetaAssets } from '@web/rollup-plugin-import-meta-assets';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

export default {
    input: 'index.html',
    output: {
        entryFileNames: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
        assetFileNames: '[name][extname]',
        format: 'es',
        dir: 'dist'
    },
    preserveEntrySignatures: false,
    plugins: [
        /** Enable using HTML as rollup entrypoint */
        html({
            minify: true,
            injectServiceWorker: false
        }),
        /** Resolve bare module imports */
        nodeResolve(),
        /** Minify JS */
        terser(),
        /** Bundle assets references via import.meta.url */
        importMetaAssets(),
        /** Compile JS to a lower language target */
        babel({
            babelHelpers: 'bundled',
            presets: [
                [
                    require.resolve('@babel/preset-env'),
                    {
                        targets: [
                            'last 3 Chrome major versions',
                            'last 3 Firefox major versions',
                            'last 3 Edge major versions',
                            'last 3 Safari major versions'
                        ],
                        modules: false,
                        bugfixes: true
                    }
                ]
            ],
            plugins: [
                [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-template-html-minifier'),
                    {
                        modules: { lit: ['html', { name: 'css', encapsulation: 'style' }] },
                        failOnError: false,
                        strictCSS: true,
                        htmlMinifier: {
                            collapseWhitespace: true,
                            conservativeCollapse: true,
                            removeComments: true,
                            caseSensitive: true,
                            minifyCSS: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            ]
        })
    ]
};
```

Finally, this is my script tag in index.html

```
<script type='module' src='./build/src/index.js'></script>
```

The issue I'm having is that I cannot import anything that is a `default export`, for example I'm trying to use axios, https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode, https://github.com/etienne-martin/device-detector-js, and other libraries that I need.

The error I'm getting in the browser console is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '[...]/node_modules/device-detector-js/dist/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

This is the same error I get for trying to import any library.

I can import named exports just fine, and everything works if I do not have any default import in the whole project.

Is it something to do with rollup? It's the first time I'm using it, until now I've always used webpack.

Is there any way to solve the issue?

Thank you very much